# Cooldown For Command On Discord Bot Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def getalt(ctx):
    msg = ["gabrielwarren2000@gmail.com:Cyber123", "leandroriveros123@gmail.com:culillo123", "albesi8@msn.com:Albakortoci1", "dryden6@yahoo.ca:toysale22", "nichlas00100@gmail.com:nich918273645", "lodevanveen@gmail.com:Lodelode1", "kylefielding2011@gmail.com:emolover123", "rubbst3in@gmail.com:rube541632789mk", "jasonfryckman@ymail.com:fryckman22", "NickSaya1@hotmail.com:blackout541", "devinquan@yahoo.com:ploopy101"]
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.author, random.choice(msg))
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Alt Has Been Seen To Your DMs")
    await client.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=2)
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.author, "Please Wait 30 Seconds Before Using This Command Again.")
```

I want to set a 30 sec cooldown for this command.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should decorate your command with

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
```

This will add a ratelimit of 1 use per 30 seconds per user.
[docs](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L907), [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/c8fef9f07145cef6c05416dc2421bbe1d05e3d33/cogs/config.py#L257)

You can change the BucketType to `default`, `channel` or `server` to create a global, channel or server ratelimit instead, but you can only have 1 cooldown on a command.

Note: In discord.py rewrite (v1.0+) instead of `BucketType.server`, you have to use `BucketType.guild`.

This will also cause a `CommandOnCooldown` exception in `on_command_error`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been looking for this forever!

Comment: Where should this code be placed in accordance to the code i have... It just keeps saying unresolved reference "cooldown"

Comment: I think you need to `from discord.ext import commands` in the file for it to resolve, then you should just be able to place it between the `@bot.command` and the `async def`

Comment: @discord.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
TypeError: cooldown() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x03B6F6D0>

Comment: is there a way to make it to where it tells them how much longer they have to wait before they can use it again... like if they do the command again

Answer (score 2):

I know a method of sending in the channel that cooldown is in process.

```
@command_name.error
    async def command_name_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            em = discord.Embed(title=f"Slow it down bro!",description=f"Try again in {error.retry_after:.2f}s.", color=color_code_here)
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

make sure you have imported bucket type. If not -

```
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown, BucketType
```

NOTE - Make sure the command cooldown event always has a different name and has to be `the_command_name_here.error` (don't make it the_command_name_here , insert the ACTUAL command name there.)