# Make Python Discord Bot send a message if on cooldown

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to set a command to a python discord bot that has a 3 second cooldown and will send a message if the command is used before the cooldown. How would I do this? This is the code for the command:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 3, commands.BucketType.channel)
async def message (ctx):
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use on_command_error and isinstance to check if its a cooldown issue and then format to your liking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cooldown For Command On Discord Bot Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python)

Answer (score 0):

By adding an "`on function error`" thing as its own function, you are able to send error messages for almost anything. While being useful for cool down errors, it can also be applied to `MissingPermissions` errors. You can check out my bot that has some more examples in a project on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/wncry/pingpain/blob/main/main.py).

I think this is what you are looking for:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 40 commands.BucketType.user) # currently 40 seconds
async def function(ctx):
    ctx.send('whatever thing here')

@function.error
async def function_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.reply('This command is on cooldown! Try again in `{e:.1f}` seconds'.format(e = error.retry_after))
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: `@function.error` will catch a error in this command. So if you're going to use a generic error message, its probably better to use `on_command_error` to catch cooldown errors in any commands; then the generic message there.