# How do you add a cooldown for a Discord bot command in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a cooldown to a Discord bot command in python. I want it so that people can only use the command once per minute and if they try to use it more it will send them a message with how much time is left. Here is my current code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(context):
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Are you seeing an error message?  Is it allowing users to use the command more frequently than once per minute? Are you just missing the message with the time remaining?

Comment: Great why was my post deleted

Comment: @RandomChannel If you believe that this question is a duplicate of another question, you should flag it as a duplicate.  Copying another users answer, even with attribution, isn't allowed.

Comment: I am receiving the following error message: NameError: name 'commands' is not defined

Comment: @MeowNerd You need to import commands from discord.ext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cooldown For Command On Discord Bot Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing following error:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(context):
```

with error `name 'commands' is not definied` means you need to import additional module.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
```