# Set slowmode delay to a DM of a bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, message-queue

I'm having a bot that accepts DM from users (There should be at least one mutual server).
Now is it possible for the users to perform a DDOS or any similar type of attack. Or simply can they spam the bot and make it unavailable for normal users?
How can I tackle this as I couldn't find any slow-mode delay for a dm_channel and is only available for text channels. I have used discord.py.
Is there a way to make something similar to slow mode delay in a DM? I mean users shouldn't be able to send multiple messages at once to the bot as DM, and should wait for the specified amount of time (or any decent amount of time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDOS can happen anywhere, but it will happen to discord first before the bots can "chat-command-spam" your bot. Which you don't really have to worry about getting DDOS'ed by a few spammers (even with a few gaming computers, spamming your bot commands in discord dm at the same time without getting noticed by discord, it won't affect your bot that much). There are cases like if you have a really expensive command in your bot, and people are frequently calling the command, then you can put a [cooldown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python) in your code for the expensive command.