# How to add timeout, python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I made a guess the character game in discord bot, (see the code below).
I want to add 30 second timeout for a player to response, but I totally dont know what to do, any help?

````
@client.command()
async def game(ctx):

    chosen_image = random.choice(embedlinks.bnhaLinks)
    channel = ctx.channel

    index = embedlinks.bnhaLinks.index(chosen_image)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x999999)
    embed.set_image(url=chosen_image)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"You have 30 seconds to guess this MHA character")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
    
    
    user_guess = (await client.wait_for('message', check=check)).content
    
    if user_guess == embedlinks.bnhaChars[index]:
        await ctx.send('Correct. Good job.')
    elif user_guess is not embedlinks.bnhaChars[index]:
        await ctx.send('Wrong. Start a new game.')```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `timeout = seconds` criteria in `wait_for`

````
@client.command()
async def game(ctx):

chosen_image = random.choice(embedlinks.bnhaLinks)
channel = ctx.channel

index = embedlinks.bnhaLinks.index(chosen_image)
embed = discord.Embed(color=0x999999)
embed.set_image(url=chosen_image)
embed.set_footer(text=f"You have 30 seconds to guess this MHA character")

await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def check(msg):
    return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel


user_guess = (await client.wait_for(timeout = 30, 'message', check=check)).content
 if user_guess == embedlinks.bnhaChars[index]:
    await ctx.send('Correct. Good job.')
 elif user_guess is not embedlinks.bnhaChars[index]:  #put this if you want user to guess only once and not multiple times
    await ctx.send('Wrong. Start a new game.')```


@game.error
async def on_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send("Time is up!")
````

Comment: When timeout time runs out I get this error: https://i.ibb.co/vhXLGHW/carbon-6.png

Comment: did you add the try and except that I added in your code?

Comment: actually, if you make a command handler for the thing, it would work too. I will edit my original answer

Comment: It worked partly, I had to add:  ```except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(embed=basicEmbedx)``` under the await ctx.send('Wrong. Start a new game.'), But now when person doesn't guess the character right message says: Time is up!. Here is picture of code: https://i.ibb.co/x1BZWmJ/carbon-7.png

Comment: remove the `try` and `except` and the `asyncio.TimeoutError` and replace `is not` with `!=`

the error handler should be enough

let me know if that fixes it!

Comment: Nothing has changed, I think that problem is in ```if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):``` I think its basically sending Time is up!, if the guess isnt right .

Comment: Can you contact me in discord? AquaRose#6892

Answer (score -1):

If you mean cooldown, then there's already a [good question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python).

Basically, all you have to do is slightly modify the beginning section of your command. Append `@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)` the line after `@client.command()`. For more information, just check out the link above.

Comment: I meant time for player to answer a bot, but thx helped anyway.