# Discord py limit command to once an hour per person

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I was wondering how you could limit a command to be used once an hour for individual people?

I was thinking about storing the users discord id with a timestamp of when they used the command but that doesn't seem like an efficient way of doing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python - Is this answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

discord.py has a `@commands.cooldown` feature, so if you wanted to make a command with a cooldown you could use this as an example:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def hourly(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello, world!')
```

Comment: Is that per user?