# How can i use discordpy cooldown command for client = discord.Client()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im trying to add cooldown for my bot so people cant spam it but the cooldown command only works for commands.bot() i am using discord.Client() and have a lot of code already setup with that and there is no way i can change it to commands.bot() now
i have a lot of these setup

```
    if "did i ask" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send(whoaskedcopypasta)
```

and this is my discord.Client()

```
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

[here is my code](https://privatebin.net/?4c594702d3437e0b#DAR5WJjTLfoyiiWgWcuMuW5Mp5YMJUJUXSToPWBwaMMV)

Comment: You can do it manually by storing the timestamp of the last use, but discord.py doesn't provide a cooldown system for Client()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also `client = discord.Client()` will not work. Use `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)`

Cooldowns are only for commands. Put this under a command - `@commands.command()` or `@client.command`:

```
@commands.cooldown(uses, cooldown_time, commands.BucketType.user)
```

e.g.

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
```

Source: [Cooldown For Command On Discord Bot Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python)

1 use per user and cooldown time is 30s

If you don't want that. You have to use a counter or time.