# How to make Discord bot read a message after a time delay?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my Discord bot to read a message from a user after a 5-second delay.

I have tried:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id == botid:
    return
  if message.content.startswith("!!"):
    return
  if message.content != "" :
    await message.channel.send(message.content)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Apparently, it only delays the time `on_message` is executed, so if a user sent "yo" 3 times (in less than 5 seconds), the bot would still read all the messages and reply "yo" 3 times, each after a 5-second delay.

How can I make the bot only read ONE message and read another one after a 5-second delay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cooldown For Command On Discord Bot Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python)

Comment: I tried throwing this as instructed. It does not work, so I suppose ```bot.event``` is different from ```bot.command```

Comment: Hi, your `time.sleep` is not *asynchronous* use `await asyncio.sleep(5)` instead.
Instead you could define a global variable storing a datetime object corresponding to the latest answered message, then using the following logic in the `on_message` listener : `if answered_time > datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5): # process here`

Comment: Then [Adding cooldown to discord bot event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71834997/adding-cooldown-to-discord-bot-event)